# Node.js createReadStream error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side-rendering, node-streams

I'm running a SSR React node.js server and I need some suggestions on how to solve my problem. My node.js server crashes/restarts on error like window is not defined etc instead of just logging & printing out a 500 error message.

Here is my stream:

```
  try {
  .......
  .......
  .......

    const markupStream = renderToNodeStream(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history} location={context}>
          <App/>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    if (context.url) {
      return res.redirect(301, context.url)
    }

    return fs.createReadStream(htmlFilePath)
      .pipe(htmlReplace('#root', markupStream))
      .pipe(replaceStream('__SERVER_DATA__', serialize(store.getState())))
      .pipe(res);
  } catch (err) {
    const errMarkup = renderToNodeStream(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history} location={context}>
          <Error500 error={err}/>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );

    logger.log({
      level: 'error',
      message: `Rendering ${req.originalUrl} fallback to Error render method`,
      ...{
        errorMessage: err.message,
        stack: err.stack
      }
    });

    return fs.createReadStream(htmlFilePath)
      .pipe(htmlReplace('#root', errMarkup))
      .pipe(res.status(500));
  } finally {
    logger.info(`Request finished ${req.originalUrl} :: ${res.statusCode}`)
    end({ route: path, componentName: componentNames[0], code: res.statusCode })
    logger.profile(profileMsg);
  }
```

I thought my catch would get those errors but apparently it's no, can someone help me point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: 1
I'm currently attemping:

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(htmlFilePath);

// Should hopefully catch the errors
readStream.on('error', function(err) {
  res.end(err);
});

return readStream.pipe(htmlReplace('#root', markupStream))
  .pipe(replaceStream('__SERVER_DATA__', serialize(store.getState())))
  .pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create  stream first before return it so that you use its error callback function:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
  readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    res.end(err);
  });
return readStream
```

Comment: const readStream = fs.createReadStream(htmlFilePath);

    // Should hopefully catch the errors
    readStream.on('error', function(err) {
      res.end(err);
    });

    // if no issues
    return readStream()
      .pipe(htmlReplace('#root', markupStream))
      .pipe(replaceStream('__SERVER_DATA__', serialize(store.getState())))
      .pipe(res);

Comment: Like the comment above?

Comment: yes. as you updated in the question. is it working ?

Comment: I'm deploying it right now. I'll let you know :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Yup. Let me know if it is working or not.you can generate error by simply adding wrong file path.

Comment: 2018-07-17T11:19:02.148Z [error]        uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
2018-07-17T11:19:02.149Z [error]        Uncaught exception

Comment: Still getting crashes ( node server restarts ) ;(

Comment: I got one function thats the last resort if it havnt been catched before which restarts it. It shouldn't reach there:
process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  logger.error('Uncaught exception', err, err.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});

Comment: If something in return readStream.pipe(htmlReplace('#root', markupStream))
  .pipe(replaceStream('__SERVER_DATA__', serialize(store.getState())))
  .pipe(res); crashes, does the on("error") catch that aswell?

Comment: Yes it should catch ideally. But can we try without using return ? because pipe will add that to res anyway.

Comment: lets continue on chat : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/176137/tushar-codehiker?tab=general